# Can I Get Online Value Using Javascript/angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to javascript and angular  so,i would appreciate your help, before I start  plz have a look at below two pictures-

[image]

After some time there is a change-

[image]

Now  some attributes in below `HTML` code has same attribute, -

```
<input type="text"
       class="menuTitleField ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-valid-required" 
       ng-model="title" placeholder="Option Name" elastic-input=""
       ng-required="isRequired" focus-on="newChild" focus-if="canFocus"
       tabindex="0" required="required" style="min-width: 0px; width: 48px;">
```

For example, there are `canFocus` or `title`, in HTML and in above picture, so how can I get the value of `canFocus`,  `title` using java script based on class name or tag name or event.target.id?

I think these values come from the sever, how can I get values of those attribute?

Plz, ask in comment for clarification, also  edit the post  for more precise question. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> so how can I get the value of `canFocus` using java script

Use either:

```
$rootScope.canFocus
```

or

```
$scope.$root.canFocus
```

Comment: does not work, 
``$rootScope.canFocus
VM87:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $rootScope is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
$scope.$root.canFocus
VM92:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1``  also I asked about title attribute, how can I get that using class or tag ?

​

Answer (score 0):

To use $rootScope,$scope in your controllers, you need to import it then you can use variables to get values like

```
$scope.title
$scope.canFocus
```

if you want to use $rootScope just use this
$rootScope.title
$rootScope.canFocus

In your HTML
title,canFocus should work with your code

Comment: I get below error when Irun your code in console - ``Uncaught ReferenceError: $rootScope is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1``

Comment: Kindly use the below link to inject $rootScope and $scope.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39951724/angularjs-uncaught-referenceerror-rootscope-is-not-defined

Comment: no idea how to modify the code in your link, could u plz  include the comple code in answer?

Answer (score -1):

Angular has an angular way of doing almost everything. In this instance I would suggest researching property binding. For example with the placeholder property you can write:

```html
<input [placeholder]="someVariable">
```

Then declare the someVariable in your component and what ever you set it to will be the placeholder and you can access it that way. The [] lets you set it to a variable in your component and will update the placeholder whenever you change it in your component. I would try experimenting with this to get an understanding for how it works.

Comment: In addition to your answer, one can also use interpolation. <input placeholder="{{someVariable}}">